# t-test when subjects contribute more than one observation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

If a (large enough) group of students take their body temperature and I want to test whether the mean body temperature is equal to 37 degrees Celsius, I can use a t-test (or an alternative such as the Mann-Whitney test).

But if some (but not all) students take their body temperature twice or thrice, then the t-test may not be appropriate because an underlying assumption is that each subject only contributes one observation. How can I correct for this? Will bootstrapped confidence intervals work?

Comment: Add a random effect for student and fit a LMM

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Knarpie's answer, you could use the lme4 package in R and run a model like:

```
lmer(outcome ~ (1|student), data=yourdata)
```

The intercept from this model represents the mean. If you centered your temperatures on 37degrees and used the lmerTest package (which extends lme4 to report p values) then the test on the intercept would say whether your data are sig. different from 37 degrees.